# Update event to outlook using outlook sdk in android

Tags: java, android, outlook, calendar

I am using outlook sdk to sync my events in my android application ,Here the google calendar insert event code

```
Event event = new Event()
    .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
    .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
    .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.");

DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00");
EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
    .setDateTime(startDateTime)
    .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
event.setStart(start);

DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00");
EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
    .setDateTime(endDateTime)
    .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
event.setEnd(end);

String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"};
event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
    new EventAttendee().setEmail("lpage@example.com"),
    new EventAttendee().setEmail("sbrin@example.com"),
};
event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
    new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
    new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
};
Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
    .setUseDefault(false)
    .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
event.setReminders(reminders);

String calendarId = "primary";
event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
```

Same like how to insert in outlook,I tried to create events but i dont know the time zone insert method

Answer (score 0):

You can change your time zone according to your nearest GMT:

```
.setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
```